# How can I use a filesize in order to read a file in WinAPI?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I've opened a file with `CreateFile` and passed that handle into both `GetFileSizeEx` and `SetFilePointerEx` which can both be used to get the file size. I then need to use ReadFile or ReadFileEx to read in the data from the whole file into a buffer.

The problem I'm having is that `GetFileSizeEx` and `SetFilePointerEx` both provide the file size as a LARGE_INTEGER type but ReadFile takes a DWORD for the number of bytes to read. Is there some workaround for this?

Comment: Rather than read the file into a user allocated buffer, consider using `CreateFileMapping()` and `MapViewOfFile()` to map a memory pointer to the file data. `CreateFileMapping()` supports files more than 4GB, and on 64bit Windows `MapViewOfFile()` can access more than 4GB of data at a time. Though, you really shouldn't be using that much sequential memory at one time to begin with, even with a user allocated buffer. There are better ways to work with large amounts of data using smaller amounts of memory.

Comment: @remy consider transforming your comment into an answer. I would like to see file mapping under windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Both [`ReadFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`ReadFileEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365468(v=vs.85).aspx) take a `DWORD` as parameter. I guess that's because Microsoft considered it to be unlikely to read more than 4GB at once.

The common approach is using the `LowPart` of the [`LARGE_INTEGER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383713(v=vs.85).aspx) union which is of type `DWORD`.

Of course you have to check manually that the size of the file is less than 4GB that means that `HighPart` is zero. If it's not then you have to perform multiple calls to `ReadFile`.

For example:

```
LARGE_INTEGER li;
DWORD actuallyRead;
LPVOID lpBuf;
... (fills li and lpBuf) ...
result = ReadFileEx(
           hFile,
           lpBuf,
           li.LowPart,
           &actuallyRead,
           NULL
         );
```